# JQUERY, select ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, select, append

Generally we create a form. By the 'add-question-btn' I add a new question to a form. We can add at once a lot of questions, as a an owner (author) we have to decide what is a 'type' of answers by selecting from dropdown list.

```
var num_question_options = [0];
var num_questions = 1;

$('#add-question-btn').click(function () {
    $('.questions').append(
        '<div class="questions-div" id="question-' + num_questions + '">' +
        '<label id="question-label" for="question-text">id:' + num_questions + '</label>' +
        '<input class="form-control" id="question-text" type="text" placeholder="Pytanie"/>' +
        '<div class="select-select-type">' +
        '<div class="dropdown">' +
        '<select title="type" class="select-type form-control" id="select-' + num_questions + '">' +
        '<option value="text">Krótka odpowiedz</option>' +
        '<option value="radio">Wielokrotny wybór</option>' +
        '<option value="checkbox">Pola wyboru</option>' +
        '<option value="menu">Menu</option>' +
        '<option value="scale">Skala liniowa</option>' +
        // tego na razie nie bedzie
        // '<option value="table">Siatka wielokrotnego wyboru</option>' +
        '<option value="date">Data</option>' +
        '<option value="hour">Godznia</option>' +
        '</select>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<ul id="answers" class="list-unstyled"></ul>' +
        '</div>'
    );
    num_question_options[num_questions] = 0;
    num_questions++
});
```

Depending on selected answer type  we should receive a place for  typing possible answers (as author). This is my function detecting a change in selected option.

**The problem is: How to find in select ID inside that function to know to which question sth should be appended.**

```
$(document).on('change','select',function(){
    var select_val = this.value;
    var field_val = parseInt($(this).attr("id")); //THIS IS PROBLEM
    alert(field_val);
    switch (select_val) {
        case 'text':
            alert('TESTtext');
            break;
        case 'radio':
            alert('TESTradio');
            var question = $('div.questions-div#question-' + field_val);
            var id = {
                questionId: field_val,
                optionId: num_question_options[field_val] + 1
            };
            question.find('ul#answers').append(
                '<li>' +
                '<input class="form-control" ' +
                'title="answer" ' +
                'id="answer-' + num_question_options[field_val] + '" ' +
                'type="text" ' +
                'onfocus="add_option(' + id.questionId + ', +' + id.optionId + ')" ' +
                'onblur="remove_option(' + id.questionId + ', +' + id.optionId + ')" />' +
                '</li>'
            );
            num_question_options[field_val]++;
            break;
        case 'checkbox':
            alert('TESTcheckbox');
            break;
        case 'menu':
            alert('TESTmenu');
            break;
        case 'scale':
            alert('TESTscale');
            break;
        case 'date':
            alert('TESTdate');
            break;
        case 'hour':
            alert('TEShour');
            break;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to be the parseInt. It cannot convert select-ID to an integer but returns NAN. Try like this:

```
var field_val = parseInt($(this).attr("id").replace(/[^\d]/g,''));
```

This would filter all non digit characters before parsing to int.

Another possibile solution would be to use data-attributes like:

```
<select data-question-id="123"> ... </select>
```

So you can retrieve the question id by `$(this).data('questionId')`.

You should also check your markup. There seem to be 3 opening div tags and 2 closing ones.